# I'm developing an Instagram app, but there's a problem

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm currently developing an Instagram app.
The app is currently undergoing inspection, but the domain won't change, but the endpoint part will change. If so, should it be inspected again?

I've looked up Meta developers' support page, but I can't find it, so I'm asking. Have you ever experienced it?